Are linear representations of finite groups in one-to-one correspondence with modules over the group algebra?
Suppose $G$ is a finite group, and $V$ is a complex vector space. It is often said that linear representations $\rho:G\to\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}\GL(V)$ correspond to modules over $\mathbb C[G]$. Indeed, if we extend $\rho$ by linearity to a $\mathbb C$-algebra homomorphism $\tilde{\rho}:\mathbb C[G]\to\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}\End(V)$, then we can give $V$ the structure of a $\mathbb C[G]$-module by setting
\begin{align}
\mathbb C[G]\times V&\to V \\
(\alpha,v)&\mapsto\tilde{\rho}(\alpha)(v) \, .
\end{align}
Similarly, if $V$ is a $\mathbb C[G]$-module, then the scalar multiplication of $V$ induces a ring homomorphism $\xi:\mathbb C[G]\to\End(V)$, which can then be restricted to a linear representation of $G$.
It seems, however, that this relationship does not define a bijective correspondence between the class of linear representations of $G$ and the class of $\mathbb C[G]$-modules. The ring homomorphism $\tilde{\rho}$ induced by a linear representation is a $\mathbb C[G]$-algebra homomorphism, so that $\rho(z)=z\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}\id_V$ for every $z\in\mathbb C$. By contrast, it seems that any ring homomorphism $\xi:\mathbb C[G]\to\End(V)$ gives rise to a linear representation of $G$. Is this correct, and if so, is there a precise sense in which we can nonetheless say that the two points of view are "the same"? The thing that I have in mind is that there is a certain equivalence of categories, but not an isomorphism of categories.

Converting my comment into an answer, for a group $G$ (not necessarily finite) and a field $K$, the following categories are equivalent (actually I think even isomorphic but this doesn't really matter):

The category of linear representations of $G$ over $K$; explicitly this is the category of pairs $(V, \rho)$ of a $K$-vector space $V$ and a group homomorphism $\rho : G \to \text{Aut}_K(V)$.

The category of modules over $K[G]$; explicitly this is the category of pairs $(A, \rho')$ of an abelian group $A$ and a ring homomorphism $\rho' : K[G] \to \text{End}_{\text{Ab}}(A)$.

The category of modules over $K[G]$ again, but now regarded as the category of pairs $(V, \rho')$ of a $K$-vector space $V$ and a $K$-algebra homomorphism $\rho' : K[G] \to \text{End}_K(V)$.


These categories are even equivalent as categories over abelian groups or $K$-vector spaces; that is, they all admit forgetful functors to abelian groups or $K$-vector spaces and the equivalences between the above categories respect these functors.
In your question you seem to have been tripped up by the distinction between 2 and 3. It is true that if $V$ is a $K$-vector space and $\rho' : K[G] \to \text{End}_K(V)$ is a ring homomorphism, not necessarily $K$-linear, then this equips $V$ with the structure of a representation of $G$ over $K$. But in this new representation $V'$, the $K$-vector space structure comes from the action of $K \subset K[G]$, and you've ignored the original $K$-vector space structure. You can do this but... in that case what was the point of introducing the $K$-vector space structure on $V$ in the first place?
The relationship between these three descriptions can be understood abstractly in terms of various adjunctions, although that might be an unnecessary complication depending on your familiarity with category theory. Concretely the point is that this is three different ways to say "an abelian group equipped with a commuting action of $G$ and $K$."

There is a bijection between representations of $G$ and a $\mathbb C$-vector space $V$ with a homomorphism $\xi\colon\mathbb C[G]\to \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(V)$ of $\mathbb C$-algebras. However, as you observe, the class of $\mathbb C$-vector spaces $V$ with a ring homomorphism $\xi\colon\mathbb C[G]\to \mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(V)$ is larger. For example, let $V=\mathbb C$ and consider the homomorphism
$$\mathbb C[G]\to \mathrm{End}(V)=\mathbb C:\sum_g\alpha_g[g]\mapsto\sum_g\overline\alpha_g,$$
where $\overline\alpha_g$ denotes the complex conjugate of $\alpha_g$.

I think I know where I went wrong, although I might find it difficult to explain how I was confused. In the direction where we start off with a $\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}\mathbb C[G]$-module $V$, I was assuming that $V$ already carried a complex vector space structure. This is not so: instead, the complex vector space structure that $V$ carries is given by restricting the scalar multiplication from $\mathbb C[G]$. The notation $\End(V)$ denotes the endomorphisms of $V$ as an abelian group, not as a vector space.
If $V$ is a $\mathbb C[G]$-module, then the induced ring homomorphism $\xi:\mathbb C[G]\to\End(V)$ can be viewed as a homomorphism of $\mathbb C$-algebras. First, we can restrict the scalar multiplication $\mathbb C[G]\times V\to V$ to $\mathbb C\times V$, endowing $V$ with a $\mathbb C$-vector space structure. Then, $\End(V)$ inherits a $\mathbb C$-vector space structure, and since $\xi(z)=z\id_V$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$, it follows that $\xi$ is a $\mathbb C$-algebra homomorphism.
We now check that the passages to and from linear representations of $G$ and $\mathbb C[G]$-modules are mutual inverses of each other, which implies that the correspondence mentioned in my question is in fact bijective. In one direction, let $\rho:G\to\GL(V)$ be a linear representation, and extend $\rho$ to a $\mathbb C$-algebra homomorphism $\tilde{\rho}:\mathbb C[G]\to\End(V)$. This gives $V$ the structure of a $\mathbb C[G]$-module, and restricting $\tilde{\rho}$ back to $G$ gives us the linear representation $\rho$ we started off with. In the other direction, suppose $V$ is a $\mathbb C[G]$-module, with the $\mathbb C$-algebra homomorphism $\xi:\mathbb C[G]\to\End(V)$ induced as in the previous paragraph. Restricting $\xi$ to $G$ gives us a linear representation $\rho$, and since there is only one way to extend $\rho$ to a $\mathbb C$-algebra homomorphism, this gives us $\xi$ back. Thus, there is a one-to-one correspondence
$$
\{\text{linear representations of $G$}\}\longleftrightarrow \{\text{$\mathbb C[G]$-modules}\}
$$
with the "$\rightarrow$" direction given by extending a linear representation $\rho:G\to\GL(V)$ by linearity, and the "$\leftarrow$" direction is given by currying the scalar multiplication $\mathbb C[G]\times V\to V$ to get a $\mathbb C$-algebra homomorphism $\mathbb C[G]\to\End(V)$, before restricting to $G$.

You could say it as follows: there is a three-way equivalence between 1) linear representations of a group $G$ over a field $K$, 2) abelian groups $A$ equipped with ring homomorphisms $K[G] \to \text{End}_{\text{Ab}}(A)$, 3) $K$-vector spaces $V$ equipped with $K$-algebra homomorphisms $K[G] \to \text{End}_K(V)$.
